# Why can't I use Xor in a calculated field in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I finally traced the problem to the Xor function (which shows as an available function in the field Expression Builder).

If I set the field to something basic, like **False Xor True**, I get an error that the expression cannot be used in a calculated field. I get the same error if I replace the "false" and "true" with column names from that table. Everything works fine if I replace the Xor with Or or And.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Oddly, it's listed in the table of [logical operators](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Table-of-operators-E1BC04D5-8B76-429F-A252-E9223117D6BD?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#tblID0EBBDAAA). But you have a simple workaround: `Field <> Field2`

Comment: If I use `=True Xor False` as Controlsource in a textbox, it works - I get `-1`. Access 2010 here.

Comment: You likely have to wrap this as a VBA function call - the SQL operators are not bitwise - but the VBA ones are.

Comment: Thanks all. Good point Zev, thanks. I'm using Access 2016 and it appears to be a bug. @AlbertD.Kallal - this isn't in SQL. It's in a calculated field.